# System Out of memory exception while sending a file

Tags: c#-4.0

I have create a application that is used for transfer of files using TCP/IP Communication.Now problem i am facing that is its throwing "Outofmemory" exception while sending a file of size more than 300 MB.Below are the lines of code.Kindly help me in resolving the issue.Exception occurring at lastline.

```
  byte[] fileName = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(m_fName); //file name
  byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(txtFilePath.Text); //file
  byte[] fileNameLen = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileName.Length); //lenght of file name
  m_clientData = new byte[fileNameLen.Length + fileName.Length + fileData.Length];
```

Comment: Well, you're reading the whole file in memory and allocating another buffer of roughly the same size, so... if the file is too big you won't have enough memory. Redesign your code to stream data instead.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi Can u give me code pls.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932%28v=vs.110%29.aspx